# How to disable command line pop ups while registering in WIX?

Tags: cmd, wix, registry

I have to register a few dlls while installing my application. I have made the installer using WIX and i register the dlls in the following pattern

```
  <CustomAction Id="RegisterXDll"
                Directory="BINFOL"
                ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe  /c /s "[BINFOL]XDll.dll" /silent'
                Return='check'>
```

But while registering the command line windows pop up each time i register a dll. How do I disable the cmd pop ups in WIX?

I have tried the following :

```
<Property Id='RegisterXDll' Value='regsvr32.exe  /c /s "[BINFOL]XDll.dll"' />
<CustomAction Id="RegisterXDll"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return='check'>
</CustomAction>
```

[BINFOL] is the location to my C:\ProgramFiles\Bin Directory. SO this is not opening up in the logs and while building the WIX project it throws a warning.
On installing, the installer crashes. What is the solution?

Comment: You should get acquainted with the quiet execution custom action: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html

Comment: You can also use "SelfRegCost=1" in your file tag in the components for which you need to use regsvr32. This is likely the easiest way to implement this. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html for more info about selfregcost

Comment: You should use Heat.exe before you build, then there is no need to self-register at all at install time. Registration data is all static data, and Heat will create a registry file for you that creates the registry entries. Running code can cause many issues.  Rule 19     https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_installer_team/2006/05/12/tao-of-the-windows-installer-part-2/

Comment: @Yan I have made the changes as you suggested. And I have run into the hurdles that I have edited just now...